# Getting error : Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

[image]

> Error : Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Getting above error when hitting aws api with cors plugin disabled in chrome.
When cors is enabled api returns correct response.

Is there any mechanism in javascript to get response from api with cors disabled in chrome?

I have added screenshots of my request and response headers for reference

***Note : Cors is enabled on server side(AWS api gateway)**

Comment: if you donot want to check CORS then disable it from server side and you will be able to send request from chrome with disable chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Lambda with Proxy Integrations, you need to specify the CORS Origin in your HTTP response.

> For Lambda or HTTP proxy integrations, you can still set up the
>   required OPTIONS response headers in API Gateway. However, you must
>   rely on the back end to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers
>   because the integration response is disabled for the proxy
>   integration.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Like this in NodeJS:

```
var response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        someReturnData
    })
};
callback(null, response);
```

Comment: The response *already* has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on it. That's not the problem, as the error message makes clear.

Comment: The request in the screen shot is for an OPTIONS request, which API-G handles. In Lambda Proxy this needs to be added manually to the GET/POST request too.

Comment: The browser isn't making the GET or POST request because the preflight response doesn't give it permission to make it.

Answer (score -1):

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Well, it isn't, we can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header in your screenshot.

So you have two options:

1. Change the response header to allow it
2. Don't send it from the client in the first place

Since `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header (your JS can't give itself permission to read the data — that would render CORS pointless) **it makes no sense at all** to send it from the client, option 2 is the correct one.

Fix your client-side code.